# Having trouble getting duckdns to work in 14.04.2 LTS

Tags: 14.04, dns, lts

I'm trying to get DNS working for my odroid-C1 Ubuntu
but running into this weird problem, error message saying symbol lookup error but my libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0 package is the newest and greatest.
can anyone please point out what i'm doing wrong here.

```
➜  ~  chmod +x duck-setup-gui.sh                    
➜  ~  ./duck-setup-gui.sh 
* Duck DNS setup by The Fan Club - version 1.0
zenity: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0.so.0: undefined symbol: 
zenity: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0.so.0: undefined symbol: 
➜  ~  apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
➜  ~  sudo apt-get install libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is quite old any way. That looks like a binary incompatibility issue.

Why not just go with very basic shell script that uses `wget` or `curl` to send an HTTP `GET` request. You may also add it to `cron` for periodic ping.

Well documented on official site: https://www.duckdns.org/install.jsp#linux-cron